# Changing column content in many rows

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `code` and in every row, the column contains `FE`. Because I do not want to go through 13,000 records, is there a quick way to replace `FE` inside 'code' with `FEU`?

While I appreciate this may be a simple question (or not?), I wasn't sure how to word it in order to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do like this:

```
UPDATE <table> SET code = REPLACE(code, 'FE', 'FEU');
```

If the column really just contains the value `FE` a simple `WHERE` clause should be enough:

```
UPDATE <table> SET code = 'FEU' WHERE code = 'FE';
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the second option :)

Comment: Yes, that should be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET code = 'FEU'
WHERE code = 'FE'
```

This will work if your column contains only the string `'FE'` and you want to replace it with `'FEU'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update `table` 
set `code` = replace(`code` , "FE","FEU") 
where (if there is a where write it here)
```

should do you

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the quickest way. You can try this:-

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET code = 'FEU'
WHERE code = 'FE'
```